# How can I check if the current string and previous string in Python code?

Tags: python, static-variables

In this code I want to compare the previous message with the current message. So I created a variable to save the previous message. I wanted to create it as a static variable then manipulate it inside the code. but the outside the x function if I declare the variable it shows an error.

```
flag = 1
        previousMessage = "abc"    
        def x():
             do_something
             currentMessage = m #got a string from code
             if(currentMessage==previousMessage):  
         #shows error in flag and previousMessgae
         #says create parameter of previousMessage and flag
                    flag=0
                    return
             else:
               do_something
               previousNews=currentNews
               flag=1
               return    
        def call():
           while True:
             if(flag==1)
                x()
                time.sleep(60)
              elsif(flag==0)
                time.sleep(60)  **strong text**
        call()
```

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors and you have so many undefined variables.

Comment: Your code is really not understandable, please correct and post back with right explanation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need. Try adding `global` before flag and previousMessage to make that variable a global variable.